# Disable paste activity for specified folder

Tags: c++, clipboard, copy-paste, api-hook

I want to block paste activity into specified folder [say "stack overflow"] , i am      already blocking the cut and copy activities from the specified folder by hooking the   functions IOFilOperation::MoveItems, and IOFilOperation::CopyItems, so which function i need to hook to achieve the paste block ......please help me